# How to simplify a term with $x$ and $y$ multiplied together

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this may seem very dumb, but for some reason I can't quite remember how to simplify an equation of the following form in order to get $x$ in terms of $y$ or vice-versa

$$ x^2 -2xy = y - y^2 $$

i keep getting stuck at the $2xy$ term

Comment: Complete the square. $$x^2-2xy+y^2=y$$Is more suggestive

Comment: what do you mean? I am still left with the $-2x$ if i try and move the 2xy term to the right and factor out the y...

Comment: Completing the square means you have something like $(x-a)^2+b$ instead of $x^2+\cdots$

Comment: ah gotcha! that edit helped. let me give it a try :)

Comment: E.g. could you complete the square in $x^2-4x+5$ (to then solve the quadratic $\cdots=0$)?

Comment: i know that there's a formula for that... [looking it up now](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/completing-the-square/)

Comment: $x = \sqrt{y} + y$

Comment: my high school math is a bit rusty, thanks so much!

Comment: I'd say $x=y\pm\sqrt y$.

Comment: sure, that is the more correct answer. in this specific question though i know x & y have to be positive though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go about solving this one, remember the property that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. This comes from the definition of squaring, to multiply something by itself, so we see that $(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)$. Using FOIL, this evaluates to the equation above.

Next, recall that any negative number squared is positive. That is, $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$. If we replace the $a$ and $b$ with $x$ and $y$, we get that $(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2$. Now, it would make sense to rearrange the equation by adding $y^2$ to each side, into the equation $x^2−2xy+y^2=y$. Using the property above, this is equivalent to $(x-y)^2=y$.

Following this step, take the square root of each side into $x-y=\pm\sqrt{y}$. the final step is to add $y$, which gives the equality $x=y\pm\sqrt{y}$. Hope this helps!